# How to register an app using a bundle id string after deleting a registered App with the same bundle string

Tags: ios

Registering an App ID

Title: 
There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.

Description:

> An App ID with Identifier 'myBundleIdstring' is not available. Please enter a different string.

This string I have registered an iOS App. But I delete it. **This AppID, I don't upload the AppStore yet.**
What can I do to register an iOS App on the developer.apple.com with that `bundle id` string?

Comment: Change your build id when register app

Answer (score 0):

If you uploaded your app to the App Store, you won't be able to reuse the bundleID. Otherwise the answer is yes. (Make sure you delete the AppID on developer.apple.com and the app in iTunesConnect)
Source: [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Comment: Important:  If you delete your app, you can’t restore it. The SKU or app name can’t be reused in the same organization. If you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.           || I found this. Must I change the bundle ID string?

Comment: @jiexishede As long as you didn't publish the App you should be able to create an AppID with a bundleID that has been used previously. Just be sure to delete the old AppID first. I tested it quickly. Created an AppID and deleted it, created a new one with same bundleID and it worked.